# How can I fetch a user's posts in his profile? - Swift & Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, fetch, posts, user-profile

Trying to **fetch a user's posts into his profile**. 
I am using a collectionview to display the data, but nothing is showing.

This is the function that I am using to fetch the user's posts with their uid. Here's my Firebase Database

[image]

```
    //variables firebase
    var currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser
    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
    let storage = Storage.storage().reference()

    //VARS
    var postsuser = [ProfileUserPosts]()


 func observeUserPosts() {

         let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

        databaseRef.child("posts").queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").queryEqual(toValue: uid!).observe(.value) { (snapshot) in

            var tempPost = [ProfileUserPosts]()

            for child in snapshot.children {

                if let childSnapshot = child as? DataSnapshot {

                    let dict = childSnapshot.value as? [String: Any]
                    let address = dict!["address"] as? String
                    let breed = dict!["breed"] as? String
                    let phoneuser = dict!["phone"] as? String
                    let photoUrl = dict!["photoUrl"] as? String
                    let url = URL(string: photoUrl!)
                    let post = ProfileUserPosts(address: address!, breed: breed!, phone: phoneuser!, photoUrl: url!)
                    tempPost.insert(post, at: 0)

                }

                self.postsuser = tempPost
                self.postsCollectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Give Firestore a look. You might find it better. In any case, it sounds like you need to understand how to architect your database. Once you do that, getting/setting/updating/deleting/querying is trivial. See [Best practices for data structure](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#best_practices_for_data_structure) documentation.

> #### Avoid nesting data
>
> Because the Firebase Realtime Database allows nesting data up to 32 levels deep, you might be tempted to think that
> this should be the default structure. However, when you fetch data at
> a location in your database, you also retrieve all of its child nodes.
> In addition, when you grant someone read or write access at a node in
> your database, you also grant them access to all data under that node.
> Therefore, in practice, it's best to keep your data structure as flat
> as possible.
>
> #### Flatten data structures
>
> If the data is instead split into separate paths, also called
> denormalization, it can be efficiently downloaded in separate calls,
> as it is needed. Consider this flattened structure:
>
> #### Create data that scales
>
> When building apps, it's often better to
> download a subset of a list. This is particularly common if the list
> contains thousands of records. When this relationship is static and
> one-directional, you can simply nest the child objects under the
> parent.
>
> Sometimes, this relationship is more dynamic, or it may be necessary
> to denormalize this data. Many times you can denormalize the data by
> using a query to retrieve a subset of the data, as discussed in
> Retrieve Data.

Comment: Hi Ron, thanks for the suggestions :) . So you think it would be best to flatten it by avoiding dividing the posts into lost and found? And simply put it as a classification within the autoId generated for the post?

Comment: yes exactly. and keep photoUrl and username under a separate `users` collection where each user is stored using their `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid`.

Comment: by users do you mean that the "author" node I currently have in my architecture where i have the uid, username, and photoUrl, that works fine? it would simply be to avoid seperating into nodes the lost & found and put it as a category inside the post?